# Can an Intel Sandy Bridge GPU run Starcraft 2?

Tags: intel-core-i7, intel-core-i5, sandy-bridge, starcraft2

Intel's Sandy Bridge GPUs are said to be a lot better than their previous ones. I'm curious about whether or not such a GPU (or maybe their second generation) can run a game like Starcraft 2 seamlessly?

(Maybe on low graphics setting. The question is whether it's playable or not.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used [Google](http://www.google.com) (`intel sandy bridge starcraft benchmark`) to find [this](http://www.anandtech.com/show/4083/the-sandy-bridge-review-intel-core-i7-2600k-i5-2500k-core-i3-2100-tested/11):

> [image: Benchmark]
>
> Starcraft II is really a strong point of Sandy Bridge's graphics. It's more than fast enough to run one of the most popular PC games out today. You can easily crank up quality settings or resolution without turning the game into a slideshow. Of course, low quality SC2 looks pretty weak compared to medium quality, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: Pro Tip: Google is a search engine. Use it to search for things.

Comment: I had found benchmarks, but the question is really directed to people who actually experienced it. Is it playable, enjoyable, etc.

Comment: It runs at 143.8 FPS on the Intel Core i5 2500K at 1024 x 768 at Low Quality. This probably scales pretty nicely to 1920 x 1200 (maybe 40 FPS?). As for whether the game is enjoyable, yes, I find SC2 to be enjoyable.